# Looking for a more elegant way to write multiple components using similar functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, material-ui, higher-order-components

I have this component that displays data but also needs to save and manipulate state. I have 5 other components that are exactly the same, except for little nuances inside of their functions. I need help finding a more elegant way to write this code, rather than having 6 files that are more or less the same.

I have tried to understand and use a HOC for this instance, but each component has its own submit call that requires data specific to that component. So, I can't seem to find a way to make a HOC work.

These are my functions:

```
  componentDidMount () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ baseForm: this.props.baseData })
      this.getDisable()
      this.setState({ loading: false })
    }, 2000)
  }

  handleSwitch = item => event => {
    this.setState({ [item]: event.target.checked })
  }

  handlePRESubmit () {
    const array = this.state.baseForm
    array.forEach(item => {
      item.isTemplate = false
      item.mark = this.state.mark
      item.isVisible = this.state.visible
      item.genesisId = item._id
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.handlePRESubmit()
    let formData = this.state.baseForm[0]
    fetch(APIURL, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    }).then(response => {
      response.json().then(data => {
        let orgId = localStorage.getItem('orgId')
        let sku = { skuId: data.data._id, type: 'verification' }
        fetch(APIURL, {})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {})
      })
    })
  }

  toggleDisabled () {
    if (this.state.assigned !== undefined) {
      this.setState({ disabled: !this.state.disabled })
    }
  }

  getDisable () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const result = this.props.assignedSku.find(e => e.name === 'Base')
      this.setState({ assigned: result })
      if (this.state.assigned !== undefined) {
        this.setState({ mark: true })
        this.setState({ visible: true })
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  handleMenu = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget })
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null })
  }
```

And this is my Card

```
        <Card id='partner-sku-card'>
          <CardHeader
            title={base.name}
            subheader={'$' + ' ' + base.price}
            action={
              <div>
                <IconButton onClick={this.handleMenu}/>
              </div>
            }
          />
          <Menu
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
          >
            <MenuItem disabled={this.state.disabled ? 'disabled' : ''}>
              Edit
            </MenuItem>
          </Menu>
          <CardActions>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Switch
                  checked={this.state.mark}
                  onChange={this.handleSwitch('mark')}
                  value='mark'
                />
              }
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Switch
                  checked={this.state.visible}
                  onChange={this.handleSwitch('visible')}
                  value='visible'
                />
              }
            />
            <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
              Submit
            </Button>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
```

Again, all of this code is being written again in 5 other files. I need an elegant way to replace the word "Base" / "base" in every aspect of this. Lets say I have Base, Mid, Top. I would need all of these functions to work for all 3, and still produce the same card at the end.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a component called `CardWrapper` or something. Then in each other file call `CardWrapper` like this:

```
class First extends Component {
    handleSwitch = () => {
        //its own implementation
    }

    handlePreSubmit = () => {
        //its own implementation
    }

    handleSubmit = () => {
        //its own implementation
    }
    //other methods that you need for each component to be different

    render(){
        return (
            <CardWrapper handlePreSubmit={this.handlePreSubmit} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} handleSwitch={this.handleSwitch} />
        )
    }
}
```

Remember that you should add all of this to all the files that share the `CardWrapper` component.

And then in `CardWrapper` you can access it by `this.props`. Ex. in the end when you have `Submit Button` that would change like:

```
<Button onClick={this.props.handleSubmit}>
    Submit
</Button>
```

Comment: oh okay, so each component would have its own logic, but then use CardWrapper as a "template" for the visual card?

Comment: @PhilipKappaz yes. You can share as much things as you want inside CardWrapper, but those methods that needs to be different for each component, then those should be on their own components

Comment: What about changing state? For instance, the <Switch/> in CardWrapper calls {this.state.disabled ? 'diabled' : ''}
would this simply change to this.props.disabled?

Comment: @PhilipKappaz no, you dont need to pass it throught props, since you are already in CardWrapper, you just access it as it is `this.state.disabled`.